# Laravel Subdomain with Landing Page and Sub projects inside

Tags: laravel, nginx, debian

I'm trying to create a landing page with links to php websites demo like the following :

```
https://demos.infinitywebservices.tn/ : landing page

https://demos.infinitywebservices.tn/demo1/public : takes to demo1 app 
https://demos.infinitywebservices.tn/demo2/public : takes to demo2 app
```

... and so on

I'm using Nginx on Debian 9 Server

My `/etc/nginx/sites-available/infinitywebservices.conf`

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    root /var/www/tony-projects/infinitywebservices/demos;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name demos.infinitywebservices.tn  www.demos.infinitywebservices.tn;

    gzip on;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_min_length 1100;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types
    text/plain
    text/css
    text/js
    text/xml
    text/javascript
    application/javascript
    application/x-javascript
    application/json
    application/xml
    application/xml+rss;     

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc|svg|woff|woff2|ttf)\$ {
                expires 1M;
                access_log off;
                add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    location ~* \.(?:css|js)\$ {
                expires 7d;
                access_log off;
                add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    ssl_certificate /...; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /...; # managed by Certbot
}
```

My Directories structures

```
/var/www
      |__tony-projects
               |__infinitywebservices
                           |__demos
                                |__ index.php (Landing page for demos.infinitywebservices.tn/)
                                |__ demo1 (Laravel Project)
                                |__ demo2 ...
                                |
                                |.....
```

**P.S**

1. I'm currently using default `.htaccess` config under `demo1` and
   `demo2` Laravel Projects
2. For now **only home page works** for me when trying to visit a sub
   project like `https://demos.infinitywebservices.tn/demo1/public/` (See : `https://demos.infinitywebservices.tn/laravel-test/public`)
3. However for
   `https://demos.infinitywebservices.tn/laravel-test/public/test`
   (Route test exists) , i'm getting `404 Not Found nginx/1.10.3`

What i'm missing here ?

Comment: Just pointing out that `.htaccess` is for apache and not nginx

Comment: Oh thanks for the info

Answer (score 1):

Instead of responding with a 404 status, you need to pass all unknown URIs to the application's controller (e.g. `/laravel-test/public/index.php`).

If you have multiple apps with a well defined directory structure, you will probably want to use a regular expression to extract the name of the application (e.g. `laravel-test`) so that the correct controller is used.

For example:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
}
location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^(/[^/]+/public) $1/index.php last;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works great for Url like `https://demos.infinitywebservices.tn/laravel-test/public/....`
However when i'm trying `https://demos.infinitywebservices.tn/laravel-test/{route}` without `/public` part, i'm getting (403 Forbidden). See [https://demos.infinitywebservices.tn/laravel-test/](https://demos.infinitywebservices.tn/laravel-test/)

Comment: You should change the regular expression to match your specific requirements, for example: `rewrite ^(/[^/]+)/ $1/public/index.php last;` might work for you.

Comment: Unfortunally it didn't work for me,

This [config](https://www.codepile.net/pile/YrxN8woW) worked insted.
 
How could i refactor this code using regular expression as you suggested ?